# Packet sniffing with TL-WN722N

Tags: kali-linux, packet

I've recently started to follow a lecture about wireless network, and I bought an external wifi card called TL-WN722N from TP-LINK to use it for packet sniffing.

I tried to use it in a Kali Linux guest on VM Ware and didn't succeed, however I read that there are two versions of firmware the 1.0 and the 2.0, it appears that I've got the 2.0, which seems to have some problem with Linux distribution, I tried to install driver from the official web site but it didn't work:

`cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/lapinou/Desktop/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_debug.o' failed
make[2]: * [/home/lapinou/Desktop/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_debug.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target 'module/home/lapinou/Desktop/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417' failed
make[1]: * [module/home/lapinou/Desktop/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-52-generic'
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2`

When I lsusb :

`Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:010c

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub`

It doesn't detect the name of the card, but the id 2357:010c seems to be the card.

I have tried to search across the internet many things but I have found nothing.

Now tree things:

- Is this possible to make the version 2.0 work on Kali Linux ?
- Does the version 2.0 include the monitor mode (which I need to sniff)
  ?
- If not, what can I buy to sniff packet in wifi ?

Comment: This is more of a technical support question than a security question. You might be able to get help on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

TL-WN722N v2 not working with kali (sniffing) but you still can use it.

```
    git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
    cd rtl8188eu/
    make all
    sudo make install
    sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
    sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0
    sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

Comment: You answer should work after upgrading the kernel version to the latest available version and installing the appropriate `linux-headers` package.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tested this model TL-WN722N v2 it is not working with kali for packet injections but you can still use it though after installing its driver.